# Spring Quartz Scheduling: How to get JobDetail from CronTriggerFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, quartz

I'm doing an upgrade of our codebase. Previously I was able to use
`org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean` and
`org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean` and this worked:

```java
protected void scheduleJobs(List<CronTriggerBean> cronTriggerBeans) {
    for (CronTriggerBean cronTriggerBean : cronTriggerBeans) {
        JobDetail jobDetail = cronTriggerBean.getJobDetail();
        try {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTriggerBean);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After switching to `CronTriggerFactoryBean` and `JobDetailFactoryBean` I don't have a way to get the `JobDetail` from the `CronTriggerBean`. What am I missing? I thought `CronTriggerFactoryBean` was supposed to be a drop-in replacement?

Comment: Cannot you simply use org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl and org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl to instantiate your jobs details and cron triggers? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235682/crontriggerfactorybean-doesnt-work-with-new-version